# How to solve the Gulp error: imagemin.jpegtran is not a function

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-imagemin

I am getting this error whenever I try to make imagemin work for any kind of image:

21:54:49] Starting 'imgmin'...

[21:54:49] 'imgmin' errored after 47 ms

[21:54:49] TypeError: imagemin.jpegtran is not a function

```
at imgmin (D:\Dropbox\Side Projects\JS learning\dev-gulp\gulpfile.js:92:26)

at bound (domain.js:419:14)

at runBound (domain.js:432:12)

at asyncRunner (D:\Dropbox\Side Projects\JS learning\dev-gulp\node_modules\async-done\index.js:55:18)

at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
```

I am currently using:

- node version 12.13.1
- npm version 6.12.1
- gullp cli version: 2.2.0
- gulp local version: 4.0.2

Here is my gulpfile.js:

```
let mainDir = 'gulp project test';

let gulp = require('gulp'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
    reload = browserSync.reload,
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    cleansCSS = require('gulp-clean-css'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    changed = require('gulp-changed'),
    uglyfi = require('gulp-uglify'),
    lineec = require('gulp-line-ending-corrector');

//set directories variables
let root = `../${mainDir}/`,
    scss = root + 'sass',
    js = root + 'src/js',
    cssDist = root + 'dist/css'
jsDist = root + 'dist/js',
    imgSRC = root + 'src/images/*',
    imgDest = root + 'dist/images/*';

//set watch files
let phpWatcher = root + '**/*php', //glob pattern
    styleWatcher = scss + '**/*.scss';


//set the order I want Gulp to concat JS files
let jsSRC = [
    js + 'file1.js',
    js + 'file2.js',
    js + 'file3.js',
    js + 'file4.js',
    js + 'file5.js',
    js + 'file6.js',
];

//set the order I want Gulp to concat CSS files
let cssSRC = [
    root + 'src/css/file1.css',
    root + 'src/css/file2.css',
    root + 'src/css/file3.css',
    root + 'src/css/file4.css',
    cssDist + 'style.css'
];


function css() {
    return gulp.src(scss + 'style.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({
            loadMaps: true
        }))
        .pipe(sass({
            outputStyle: 'expanded'
        }).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(lineec())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDist))
}

function concatCSS() {
    return gulp.src(cssSRC)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({
            loadMaps: true,
            largefile: true
        }))
        .pipe(concat('style.min.css'))
        .pipe(cleansCSS())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps/'))
        .pipe(lineec())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDist));
}

function javascript() {
    return gulp.src(jsSRC)
        .pipe(concat('project.js'))
        .pipe(uglyfi())
        .pipe(lineec)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(jsDist));
}

function imgmin() {
    return gulp.src(imgSRC)
        .pipe(changed(imgDest))
        .pipe(imagemin([
            imagemin.gifsicle({
                interlaced: true
            }),
            imagemin.jpegtran({
                progressive: true
            }),
            imagemin.optipng({
                optimizationLevel: 5
            })
        ]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(imgDest));
}

function watch() {
    browserSync.init({
        open: 'external',
        proxy: 'http://localhost/dev',
        port: 8080,
    });
    gulp.watch(styleWatcher, gulp.series([css, concatCSS]));
    gulp.watch(jsSRC, javascript);
    gulp.watch(imgSRC, imgmin);
    gulp.watch([phpWatcher, jsDist + 'project.js', cssDist + 'style.min.css'])
}


exports.css = css;
exports.concatCSS = concatCSS;
exports.javascript = javascript;
exports.imgmin = imgmin;
exports.watch = watch;


let build = gulp.parallel(watch);
gulp.task('default', build);
```

I found someone had the same error with gifsicle and fixed it by reinstalling the plugins but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer and I write it here in case someone will have the same issue.
imagemin.jpegtran has been substitute by imagemin.mozjpeg. Also, I had to install mozjpeg (npm install --save-dev imagemin-mozjpeg) as, for the time I am writing, it seems it is not installed together with imagemin.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but it happened in the alpine version of node (node:16.11.1-alpine3.14) in docker.

The problem was that some OS libs were missing and it was solved by adding the libs (**bash, autoconf, libtool, libltdl, libpng-dev, lcms2-dev, GCC, g++, automaker**):

```
RUN apk add --update \ 
    bash \ 
    autoconf \ 
    libtool \ 
    libltdl \ 
    libpng-dev \ 
    lcms2-dev \ 
    gcc \ 
    g++ \ 
    automake \ 
    make \ 
    nasm \
&& rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```